# ajaxError Reset

Tags: jquery, ajax

G'day All,

A page that is created by a 3rd party they have the following code:

```
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
        alert(SOME ERROR HERE);
    });
```

I can add my own code but cannot touch theirs I would like to override that because it is messing with my ajax get. By the time it gets to my step theirs has already run so if I could somehow get it reset or nullified that would be great.

I have written the exact same code with no alerts in my function but it ignores it and calls theirs.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but **it's impossible**. The 3rd party added that event listener, and you can also **add** event listeners, but you can't remove them.

You can only add more `.ajaxError()` handlers and try to 'counter-attack' the 3rd party behavior, but you can't remove it.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for that. Based on what you said I decided for a test to see what would happen by adding code above theirs. Meaning mine is first but yet theirs kicks off. Giving the alert. So there is not much I can do i suppose

Answer (score 16):

You can do :

```
$(document).off('ajaxError');
```

See [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/ajax.js#L190) for more info

Answer (score 2):

You can disable **all** global event handlers for an ajax call, by setting `global: false`. See [Disabling some jQuery global Ajax event handlers for a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436195/disabling-some-jquery-global-ajax-event-handlers-for-a-request), and [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).
You can still use the handlers that you define locally in your ajax call.