# Cancel jQuery ajax error in .fail() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm working on a site that has a global Ajax error handler in the main page template, like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, thrownError) {
        postError(thrownError);
    })
```

This updates the page with information about an error from an Ajax request. I am working on a specific Ajax call where I need errors to be handled differently, it will just silently select a value without doing anything about the error. The function is in a handler for a DevExtreme SelectBox that must return a `Promise`:

```
return $.ajax({
        // stuff
    }).fail(function (request, status, error) {
        // set value
    });
```

This does what its supposed to in regards to setting the value, but the Ajax error handler still fires. I've tried setting the error to null in the `.fail()` function but it still gets posted. Is there a way to disable the `ajaxError` handler for just this one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to prevent bubbling the error up for a particular case. See the following post and I believe this is what you are looking for:

[Javascript: How to stop multiple jQuery ajax error handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051452/javascript-how-to-stop-multiple-jquery-ajax-error-handlers)

Hope this helps!