# jQuery AJAX - Overwrite error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have have plenty of AJAX calls within the application, each of them have it's own error handler.

I'm looking for a way to avoid the error handler for a certain status.

When using the `$.ajaxError`, it's being called AFTER the handler of the individual AJAX was already executed.

Is there a way to abort executing the AJAX error event, in case of a specific status?

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Can you provide some code please ?

Comment: I think this is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436195/disabling-some-jquery-global-ajax-event-handlers-for-a-request

Comment: Thanks, This is the other way around than suppressing the ajaxError.  Here I would like to suppress the error so that only the ajaxError will be taken (in case of a certain status)

Comment: Or in other words, suppress the local error for the favor of the global error